# Play a wav-file while hovering a word

Tags: html, audio, wav

I'm looking for a way to play very small wav-files when hovering a word in a text. Usually I have around 20 words in a text which you can hover and will be pronounced. 
bgsound was my solution, but that did not work with FF and Chrome. I added a sample of my previous solution and the problem.

Thanks in advance, Adriaan

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

In IE this works fine. In FF and Chrone it will not work.
Hovering the word is enough to fire the wav-file. <br /><br />
Great, this works, f.e. the sound of <a href="#" onmouseover="document.all.music.src='sound/cardiaal.wav'">glass</a> and that works well. Also a small one like this
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.all.music.src='http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Samples/Perverse/Utopia%20Critical%20Stop.WAV'">beep</a>. but it won't work in FF and Chrome. 

<bgsound id="music" autostart="true" loop="1" src="#"></bgsound>

<br />
<br />

I'm curious how to get the same result with the html audio-tag.
<br /><br />

This works in all browsers, but I do not want the controls. 

<audio controls="controls">
  Your browser does not support the <code>audio</code> element.
  <source src="http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Samples/Perverse/Utopia%20Critical%20Stop.WAV" type="audio/wav">
</audio>
I just want to hear the sound when I hover a word.<br />
How to fix this?
<br />
<br />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think embedding your question in the html is helpful for the reader.

Comment: <audio> is a html statement, so I do not see the problem.

Comment: My point was that your actual question (the sentence ending in a `?`) along with other details of your problem is intermingled with your sample code making your problem more difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

I got the following to work without displaying the audio control. I only have IE8, though, so I don't know whether it works for IE. IE8 does not support the 'audio' element, though your bgaudio code works there.

I bet there is a way to pass the audio src as a parameter, but I'm too much of a beginner to know how to do that. If you figure it out, can you post that?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<audio id="audioDrip"
  <source
    src="http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/Samples/Perverse/Utopia%20Critical%20Stop.WAV" type="audio/wav">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<a href="#" onmouseover="playAudioDrip()">drip</a>

<script> 
    function playAudioDrip() 
    { 
        audioDrip.play(); 
    } 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

W3C says bgaudio is a 'non-conforming element' and shouldn't be used. So it makes good sense to try and figure out a different way to do this. But for folks with IE8, maybe it is okay to get rid of the "Your browser does not support the audio element." message and have the bgaudio method invoked where the error message normally resides.